# Can you install documentation for existing gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

Rubyinside mentioned [a blog post](http://buddingrubyist.com/2009/02/14/how-to-speed-up-gem-installs-10x/) on how to speed up gem installation by not installing RI or RDoc.

Is it possible to install a gem and subsequently install documentation at a later date, so you can hack in haste and RTFM at leisure?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
> gem help rdoc

Usage: gem rdoc [args] [options]
Options:
      --all                        Generate RDoc/RI documentation for all
                                   installed gems
      --[no-]rdoc                  Include RDoc generated documents
      --[no-]ri                    Include RI generated documents
  -v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to rdoc
Arguments:
  GEMNAME       gem to generate documentation for (unless --all)
Summary:
  Generates RDoc for pre-installed gems
Defaults:
  --version '>= 0' --rdoc --ri
```

Comment: How about modifying the documentation of an already installed gem? My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776491/generating-rdocs-for-locally-installed-gems

Answer (score 10):

If you run `gem rdoc --all` it will generate documentation for all your gems.

You can also use the following command to generate docs for gems in your bundle:

```
bundle list | egrep '\*' | sed -e 's/* \(.*\) (.*)/\1/g' | xargs -n 1 gem rdoc
```

You may need to adapt to your needs and also if bundle changes its output format.

Comment: Thanks simao, I am getting too much information, so now I find myself running `bundle list | egrep '\*' | sed -e 's/* \(.*\) (.*)/\1/g' | xargs -n 1 gem rdoc --no-ri 2>&1 | grep -v "Gem::SourceIndex"`