# Is it possible to generate Rdocs after a gem has already been installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

I installed a gem using the `--no-rdoc` flag but now I am regretting it!

Can I somehow generate my rdocs without having to reinstall the gem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you install documentation for existing gems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664651/can-you-install-documentation-for-existing-gems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the `gem rdoc` command.

See `gem help rdoc` for details.