# Generating RDOCs for locally installed gems

Tags: ruby, documentation, rubygems, rdoc

I am trying to contribute to a gem I recently took interest in - Nesta. The developer has done a great job in creating one of the lightest, thinest CMSs you can find and I want to document it. I have read through the code and commented on a few methods to the best of my knowledge.

However, I seek to test this out locally by calling `gem server` and seeing the changes on my machine before pushing it online.

Things I have tried:

1. Manual edit.

   - Documented the file.
   - Fired up `gem server`.
2. Using the `gem` tool.

   - Documented the file.
   - Ran `gem rdoc nesta --rdoc`
   - Restarted `gem server`

All to no avail. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can preview generated html pages without installing a modified version of the gem on your machine. Add this to nesta's Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
Rake::RDocTask.new('doc') do |i|
  i.rdoc_files = FileList['lib/**/*']
end
```

and type `rake doc`. Then view generated `html/index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've installed the version that you've modified, not the original version?

If you've installed the modified version, but have forgotten to install the rdoc, see [Can you install documentation for existing gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664651/can-you-install-documentation-for-existing-gems)

Comment: how do I install the modified version of the gem? The gem installed in some directory under RVM. I changed the files there. I didn't copy it from it's install directory. Do I still have to reinstall it?